# Call JavaScript function when all Ajax calls finished

Tags: javascript, ajax

need so help with some JavaScript code that isn't working as expected.

The Application sends files names to the server via Ajax calls to be processed but I want to tell the database that current import has been completed when they are all done. The issue I'm having is the code to update the database with the state runs before any of the ajax calls run.

I have ready in a number of area on the web that you could potentially create a promise array to track that but JavaScript honestly being a weak point of mine, I'm not sure how to I would go about implementing it.

below are my current code snippets:

function that loops through file names:

```
function importFiles() {
    serverImporterInit();
    let files = getFiles();
    if (files) {
        showImportProgressModal(files);
        let looper = $.Deferred().resolve();
        $.when.apply($, $.map(files, function (file, index) {
            let fileStatusElement = document.getElementById('file-' + index + '-status');
            let fileErrorElement = document.getElementById('file-' + index + '-error');
            looper = looper.then(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    return import_file_request(file, fileStatusElement, fileErrorElement);
                }, 2000);
            });
            return looper;
        })).then(function () { 
        });
    }
}
```

ajax call to the server:

```
function import_file_request(file, element, errorElement) {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();
    fileImportStatusInProgress(element);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/importer/manual_import',
        data: {'file': file.toString()},
        success: function(data) {
            fileImportStatusSuccess(element);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            fileImportStatusFailed(error, element, errorElement);
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Both of these functions have been derived from other tutorials across the web but I'm not entirely sure if they ever did what I originally intended as I have only just got around to trying to track the completion status due to another requirement.

Any help would be great. Also if there any other details I can include to make this question a little better for other please let me know and I will update accordingly.

Update
I have tried to update the code to use a promise array but still having no luck.

File loop:

```
const importFiles = async (files) => {
    serverImporterInit()
    const filesLength = files.length
    showImportProgressModal(files);
    for (let i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
        const requests = files.map((file) => {
            let fileStatusElement = document.getElementById('file-' + i + '-status');
            let fileErrorElement = document.getElementById('file-' + i + '-error');
            return import_file_request(file, fileStatusElement, fileErrorElement) // Async function to import file
            .then(console.log(file + " successfully imported"))
            .catch(e => console.log('Error'))
    })
        await Promise.all(requests)
        .then(serverImporterClose())
        .catch(e => console.log(''))
    }
}
```

File import request to sever:

```
function import_file_request(file, element, errorElement) {
    fileImportStatusInProgress(element);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/importer/manual_import',
            data: {'file': file.toString()},
            success: function(data) {
                fileImportStatusSuccess(element);
                resolve();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                fileImportStatusFailed(error, element, errorElement);
                reject();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using jQuery so I try to give a jQuery based solution without the native promise. I think you should either use the native promise combined with the builtin `fetch()` function and no jQuery or jQuery alone.

The key is to use `$.map()` to give back an array of promises and then wait for all of them using `$.when()`. Also it is always important to **return** the jQuery promise.

```
function importFiles() {
  var files = getFiles();
  if (files) {
    showImportProgressModal(files);
    serverImporterInit();
    var promises = $.map(files, function(file, index) {
      let fileStatusElement = document.getElementById('file-' + index + '-status');
      let fileErrorElement = document.getElementById('file-' + index + '-error');

      return import_file_request(file, fileStatusElement, fileErrorElement)
    })
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(results) {
      serverImporterClose();
      results.forEach(function(result) {
        if (result) {
          console.log("yay, success");
        }
        else {
          console.log("failed");
        }
      })
      hideImportProgressModal(files);
    });
  }
}

function import_file_request(file, element, errorElement) {
    fileImportStatusInProgress(element);
    // MUST return the promise here
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/importer/manual_import',
        data: {'file': file.toString()},
        success: function(data) {
            fileImportStatusSuccess(element);
            return true;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            fileImportStatusFailed(error, element, errorElement);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```